# Unique domain for each organic group

Tags: organic-groups

Im trying to make it that each OG has its own URL eg. www.group1.com, www.group2.co.uk etc There was a module to do this apparently but not for D7. You'd think it streight foreward but it isnt. Probably due to path module. Everything I try gives me permission errors. Im using D7 and Cpanel. Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this with the Rules module, and the [Domain Rules](http://drupal.org/project/domain_rules) module.

> Adding Rules module actions related to Domain Access module.
>   Allowing automation of different actions needed to create/modify/delete domains.
>
> First version includes:
>
> - rules_action_create_domain - create new domain using given arguments
> - rules_action_delete_domain - delete existing domain
> - rules_action_set_user_defaults_domain - set a given role access to a given domain
> - rules_action_set_node_domain - set domain to a node
> - rules_action_set_domain_theme - set a theme to a given domain

Answer (score 1):

I created GitHub project that provides a OG sub-module called [OG Domain Access](https://github.com/ejanus/og_domain_access) which does exactly this. It also allows you to override CSS/JS/Template suggestions per domain group. At the core of the module, hook_node_grants_alter is used to prevent access to content that does not belong to the domain the user is logged into.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Subdomain](https://www.drupal.org/project/subdomain) module in its "one subdomain per organic group" mode, and then additionally provide DNS CNAME aliases from your domains to these subdomains that were assigned to the Organic Groups.